# (Scraping) Handling products with varying identifiers/numbers

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I'm scraping a set of products from various retail sites, but unfortunately ~10% of the products have mix matched product model numbers. This is troubling because ideally I need an automated way of comparing product information/pricing between these sites.

The information I am able to gain:

- Product Brand
- Product Name <-- These have minor variations at times also
- Product Model Number <-- This is what I use as the "unique"
- Misc. Product Information (Descriptions, ratings, etc)

One retail site may list a product as: **ABC123-123** while another may do **ABC123123** (without dash). This is the bulk of the issues, however sometimes it's more varying such as **ABC123 123 B** vs **Brand ABC123123** (combines the entire string and tags on the literal brand in the front rather than the initial).

My proposal is to regex all incoming variables by removing spaces and dashes.

```
var cleanedProduct = product.replace(/-|\s/g,"");
```

This should reduce my "chances" at mix matches as much as possible. For the remaining I have two ideas:

- **Semi-automated**: Fuzzy search new products with product names, if a match exists store backup model numbers. Then I can review when this exception is found for approval.
- **Manual**: Check new products and add them to the exception list so it triggers matching up to the correct/baseline model number

*During production it's expected to be ~5000 products, only 80-120 new products annually.*

Just curious if someone came into the same issue, ideally using UPC codes... but I am not given that information.

Comment: You solution looks good enough. Are there other cases where '-' and spaces are not involved and something else is there?

Comment: The second example, such as **ABC123 123 B** vs **Brand ABC123123**. But these make up a VERY small amount of products.

Comment: Oh. So, removing 'Brand' like others is not appropriate or its just an example to make your point.